# About openGauss, what is the command to view the table structure properties or the system table?

Tags: open-gauss

About openGauss, what is the command to view the table structure properties or the system table?For example, table details, index details, constraint information, partition table information, user information, statistics information, version information, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The \d+ command shows the table properties, including the columns and their types and properties, indexes, constraints, rules, and triggers. It is functionally equivalent to the same command on PostgreSQL.

```
\d+ table_name
```

If you only need basic information then you can use \d instead.

For more information you can check this [tutorial](https://docs.opengauss.org/en/docs/3.1.1/docs/BriefTutorial/viewing-objects.html).

Comment: Insted of saying "does what you need" please describe in words, what does it really do